# how to insert css into html for blogger gadget

Tags: html, css, insert, blogger

so I was so proud of myself since I was finally able to make some basic html/css codes myself, but then when I copied them into a blogger html/javascript gadget, it didnt work.. can you please tell me where should I insert the css code? should I add something?

thank u[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Yry.png)

```css
#rectangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #F8E7E1;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle">
  <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/mykoreaobsession">
      <img border="0" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Bf7mwFGwROk/V6SKqUYGSYI/AAAAAAAAB_4/OeB9p4MTUSULT6RlPgOAKoZg1CvxFeetACLcB/s1600/facebook.png" height=30 width=30/>
    </a>
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/111582473236918769201">
      <img border="0" src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-vtaPYY5ddhc/V6SKqYEhUbI/AAAAAAAAB_8/E2ai63DrRJ4228zGYfr1jXZCHO3bbZpXgCLcB/s1600/googleplus.png" height=30 width=30/>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.instagram.com/_ou_ma_">
      <img border="0" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Zr10DhdxK4E/V6SKqeryEhI/AAAAAAAACAA/0JVOCrBiNr0SUxWlT6a9zfS9CRQF5FgpgCLcB/s1600/instagram.png" height=30 width=30/>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.pinterest.com/oumasobsessions">
      <img border="0" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-YAm1EgkIZ5Y/V6SKqj9e47I/AAAAAAAACAE/yFBPhfkeshMvCP5FSg7U4fJY4FERZpaHQCLcB/s1600/pinterest.png" height=30 width=30/>
    </a>
    <a href="mailto:ouma.kwon@gmail.com">
      <img border="0" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-tSE8rDvY-Fo/V6SK5hqc5RI/AAAAAAAACAI/vnm5EtELjZsf9afdwnlqJxJxlnh7ootlACLcB/s1600/mail.png" height=30 width=30/>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.bloglovin.com/blogs/my-korea-obsession-13763831">
      <img border="0" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/--_hjcSVNzZ0/V6SL_c7UctI/AAAAAAAACAU/wk5pkshnNBgPvX7rCDIRE4T-N81Z1JdzQCLcB/s1600/bloglovin.png" height=30 width=30/>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your CSS code to a CSS file. As an alternative, you can wrap it with a `style` tag:

```
<style>
#rectangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #F8E7E1;
  padding: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: thank you so much. I tried it before but it didn't work, must have written something wrong

Answer (score 0):

CSS code belongs either into a seperate style section between `<style>...</style>` tags or a separate CSS file included via `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">`. Normally, both are notated in the `<head>`-section of your HTML file.

You will find tons of information about this in the web, e.g. here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: I used the style thingie before but it didn't work, and it magically does now.. I think I wrote it wrong or something. Thnak you

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you switch to "Edit HTML" mode?

Comment: yep. this one is already solved, I forgot to put the <style>..</style> thingies